# What's the difference between NTLMv2 and Kerberos?

Tags: active-directory

### What I understand:

- NTLMv1/v2 is a shorthand for Net-NTLMv1/v2 and hence are the same thing.
- NTLM (without v1/v2) means something completely different.
- NTLM hashes are stored in the Security Account Manager (SAM) database and in Domain Controller's NTDS.dit database.
- Net-NTLM hashes are used for network authentication (they are derived from a challenge/response algorithm and are based on the user's NT hash).
- Kerberos uses tickets to authenticate

### My questions:

1. Why use NTLMv2 when you can use Kerberos instead for authentication (ie SMB)
2. Why does the account you want to log in needs an SPN for Kerberos? Can't you just use Kerberos for logging in any account?
3. Is NTLMv2 used for simply logging in accounts?
4. Is NTLMv2 used in SMB?
5. Kerberos is used in LDAP, right?
6. Heard Kerberos is used to retrieve resources from the domain controller, what are some resources?
7. Why is NTLMv2 still used, and where
8. Where is Kerberos used other than logging into accounts with SPNs
9. What does Kerberos really log you in? A shell? Account?
10. What does NTLMv2 really log you in? A shell? Account? File share?
11. What are SPNs, what are used for and where

Comment: Not sure this is really related to programming. Are you trying to develop a program using these or is it a general question? If the latter there might be more suitable forums for this, possibly Server Fault, but do check their help section and rules first.

Answer (score 6):

There are far too many questions here to answer individually, so here is a better way to think about it.

NTLM is a p2p authentication protocol. The client sends a ticket directly to the server and the server can validate it directly or send it off to a a Domain Controller to validate. This is why workgroup PC to workgroup PC can succeed with just a username and password. However, with NTLM you have no way to prove the server you've sent the ticket to is actually the server you want to send it to. This means no server authentication, and therefore means no mutual authentication.

Kerberos always relies on a third server to authenticate you *and* the server you're trying to authenticate to. You do this by first authenticating to the KDC (Domain Controller), and then with that resultant ticket request a new ticket to the target service. The KDC uses the SPN to find the details of the target service in the directory and encrypts the identity to a key only the target service knows.

Then the client sends the new ticket to the target service, the service decrypts the ticket, and then encrypts a response to the client with a key shared in the encrypted ticket. Since only the named server can decrypt the ticket (and therefore see the shared encryption key), the client has evidence it's talking to the service with the given SPN. That provides server authentication, and therefore mutual authentication. If you don't have an SPN you can't ask the KDC to create a ticket that only the server knows.

If you don't have an SPN, there is a lesser known flow of Kerberos called user-to-user, which requires an out of band process to exchange additional tickets. This is rarely used because it's more complicated and just shifts the server auth problem.

This explains why both protocols exist. NTLM exists where there isn't a KDC, or the service isn't configured with an SPN. The downside is NTLM is less secure.

In Windows-land NTLM and Kerberos are mostly interchangeable because they're wrapped in a separate protocol called SPNEGO, which is an authentication negotiation protocol. Kerberos is usually tried first, and falls back to NTLM if Kerberos fails. In the majority of cases SPNEGO is used in place of Kerberos or NTLM so whether something uses Kerberos or NTLM is entirely dependent on whether the client can get a Kerberos ticket.

Kerberos is generally always attempted. When you log into your domain-joined machine Kerberos is always used. NTLM can be used without additional work because it is an artifact of the credentials you typed in.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/ntlm-and-kerberos-authentication
- **Kerberos**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-authentication-overview
- **NTLM**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/ntlm-overview

**What is NTLM**?: It is an Authentication Protocol that is used in older versions of Windows. But it is still being used today world. If for any reason Kerberos fails to, NTLM will be used instead. NTLM stands for **N**ew **T**echnology **L**AN **M**anager

**What is Kerberos**?: It is also an Authentication Protocol, it is a default authentication protocol on Windows version above Win2K, to replace the NTLM Auth protocol.

| No | Kerberos | NTLM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kerberos is an Open Source software and offers free services | NTLM is the proprietary Microsoft authentication protocol |
| 2 | Kerberos supports delegation of authentication in multi-tier application | NTLM does not support delegation of authentication |
| 3 | Kerberos supports two factor authentication such as smart card logon | NTLM does not support smart card logon |
| 4 | Kerberos has the feature of mutual authentication | NTLM does not have future of mutual authentication |
| 5 | It provides high security | While NTLM is less secured as compared to Kerberos |
| 6 | Kerberos is supported in Windows 2000, XP and later versions | NTLM is also supported in earlier windows versions of Windows 95, 98 ME, and NT 4.0 |

**NTLM Authentication Illustration**:

[image]

**Kerberos Authentication Illustration**:

[image]